# How to update my drivers?

Tags: drivers, 20.04

I just changed my Operating System to `Ubuntu 20.04` from `Windows 10`. On windows, I used an external software to manage my drivers and update them. But I cant figure out how to do that on Ubuntu. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for that. Ubuntu will take care of it by default but there is one important thing to note: Ubuntu is not a rolling release so software is not upgraded/updated immediately. As with anything in Ubuntu: we go for stable not for newest. If you want the newest by default Ubuntu is not the OS to pick. You could choose something like "Debian unstable". Generally only emergency/security updates will happen in between (there have been exceptions).

We also tend to use generic drivers and those will update every point release.

20.04 LTS as an example: it got a big update when 20.10 arrived (that is a point release called 20.04.1. What happens is that the hardware stack from 20.10 gets added to 20.04) and will get another one when 21.04 (= 20.04.2), 21.10 (= 20.04.3) and so on arrive. Those point release contain new sets of drivers if those are released.